# Best way to connect models to collections with backbone js

Tags: collections, backbone.js, view, models

I'm having some problems with linking my models - which have their own views into a collection. I don't know whether I am doing this the correct way or not. I don't know if I need a view for the collection as well.

Here is the barebones code for my app.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend ({
initialize : function () {
    new ModelView({model:this});
}
});

var ModelCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
initialize : function () {
    console.log('collected');
    this.on("add",function(){
        console.log('added model');
    });
},
model: Model
}); 

var Models = new ModelCollection;

var ModelView = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize : function () {
    console.log('view is loaded');
    this.render();
    this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
},
el: $('#menu'),
render : function () {
    var data = this.model.toJSON();
    var template = Handlebars.compile($("#menu-template").html());
    $(this.el).html(template(data));
    return this; 
},
});

var ModelCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize : function () {
    console.log('Collection view created');
    Models.bind('add', this.addOne, this);
    Models.bind('reset', this.addAll, this);
    Models.bind('all', this.render, this);
},

addOne : function (model) {
    console.log('working');
    var view = new ModelView({model: model});
}
});

var ModelCollection = new ModelCollectionView;
```

I don't know if i'm missing something here or whether I need this bit of code

```
var model = new Model();
Models.push(model);
```

I just can't find a basic example of this anywhere. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the code you show, I would suggest you go through a tutorial on `backbone.js` (Google is a good place to start). There is a lot of them out there, and it will help you understand the relations between views, models and collections.

That being said, it seems strange to have a model which only creates a new view of the model.
The whole point of a model is that is should contain data, which is again shown in the view.
Look at how this example is distributing it:

```
//Some doctors in an array, just mockupdata to create models from
var someDoctors = [
    { name: "SomeName1" type: "Surgeon" },
    { name: "SomeName2" type: "Surgeon" },
    { name: "SomeName3" type: "Surgeon" },
    { name: "SomeName4" type: "Surgeon" }
];

//define product model
var Doctor = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        favoriteTool: "Stethoscope"
    }
});

//define a hospital collection of doctors
var Hospital = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Doctor
});

//define individual doctor view which renders a template based on data from the model
var doctorView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    className: "doctor-container",
    template: $("#doctorTemplate").html(),

    render: function () {
        var tmpl = _.template(this.template);
        $(this.el).html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

//define the hospital view
var hosptialView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#doctors"),

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new Hosptial(someDoctors);
        this.render();
    },

    // go through all models in the hospital and calls renderDoctor for each model
    render: function () {
        var that = this;
        _.each(this.collection.models, function (item) {
            that.renderDoctor(item);
        }, this);
    },

    //create a view for the item (doctormodel) and appends it to this views el.
    renderDoctor: function (item) {
        var doctorView = new DoctorView({
            model: item
        });
        this.$el.append(doctorView.render().el);
    }
});

//create instance of hospital view
var hosptial = new hosptialView();
```

As you can see, the Collection is connected to doctor, the collection view creates a doctorview for each doctor and appends it to it self.

If you want to listen for adds to the collection, do it in the collectionview initialize, and call renderDoctor:

```
Hospital.bind('add', this.renderDoctor, this);
```

Comment: Thanks. That was really helpful. The comments have helped me understand the missing parts to my thinking and understanding. Will try and implement it this way and let you know how I get on. Thanks

Comment: Just wanted to check that there isn't any inconsistances with your example? There seems to be 'doctors', 'doctor' and 'Doctor'. Are these all meant to be the same? @jedimorten

Comment: Ok...so everything seems to be working - except I get an extra model rendered which is empty and has no attributes. The only reason I know it's there is because I can see it in the console @jedimorten

Comment: Actually I solved my problem - I was passing in data and not my models. Thanks so much for your help